# Can't add Azure CloudService Project to existing solution

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-cloud-services

Goal: Convert an existing MVC application running on Azure AppServices to run on Azure CloudService. (need to add a library that needs this)

Problem: Error message (below) and the CloudService role appears non-functional

Visual Studio 2017 (15.2 (26430.6))

**Actions**:

- Added new Cloud Services project to the existing solution

  Did not add any roles

  OK (project created without error)
- Added a Role to the CloudService project

  "WebRole in project"

  Selected the MVC application that already existed in the project

  Press OK, error occurs

  Note, the project described in the error is the MVC project (not the CloudServices one), so we also removed the NuGet reference and retried with the same result.

Error (retyped):

> Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> The following NuGet packages could not be installed in project XXXXXXXXX:
>
> WindowsAzure.Storage (version ‘(unknown)’): Value cannot be null. Parameter name: path1

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem here...stinky error message

The problem was that the Azure SDK was not installed correctly. Modified the installation to include the Azure workload and this fixed the problem.

The Convert to Azure Cloud Services became available and that seems to have worked.

There was no message that the workload was not installed, perhaps because the machine had a version of the Azure SDK installed from previous work in VS 2015. Dunno.